# Time Range Selection in C#

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0

How can I know current time(not date) is between JobStart & Job End Time

```
    var JobStartTime  = new DateTime(2012,1,1,9,0,0,DateTimeKind.Local);    //09:00AM
    var JobEndTime = new DateTime(2012,1,1,18,0,0,DateTimeKind.Local);      //06:00PM
    var CurrentTime = DateTime.Now;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [DateTime.TimeOfDay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday.aspx) Property

```
if (CurrentTime.TimeOfDay >= JobStartTime.TimeOfDay &&
    CurrentTime.TimeOfDay <= JobEndTime.TimeOfDay)
{

}
```